# How to use Selenium IDE on Google Colabs without requirement of custom library e.g. Kora?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory, kora

Aim to control an eToro account from site with signals of buying and selling given to Selenium API.

Using Selenium on local machine is done using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Chrome Webdriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Doing this online through Colabs is more difficult as importing working chomedriver software is not as straightforward. Have had some consideration of using the Kora library: https://yugdamor.medium.com/selenium-inside-google-colab-febe6d797ce4?source=friends_link&sk=3954d724ca6dc396c3af89b289c0e802.

Kora does not seem to offer the same exact features as Selenium, such as being able to control the webpage itself; navigation and clicking on elements. What efficient ways are there to either import chromedriver to Colabs or use Kora in the way intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use my `kora` library, the path to chromedriver is `/usr/bin/chromedriver`.

You can also look under the hood here [selenium.py](https://github.com/korakot/kora/blob/master/kora/selenium.py).

It's just a few lines of code to help you install selenium and chrome on Colab.